# VS2017 WebSite options are listed under previous versions node. Are they obsolete?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2017

the website options are listed under previous versions node. Does it mean it is obsolete? What should be used going forward?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much, but you may still have a need for them, so they are still there.

These produce projects using the "Web Site" as opposed to the "Web Application" project format - which among other features don't have a .csproj file, typically require you to deploy all your raw code (.aspx and .cs/.vb in the App_Code folder), etc.

[Microsoft recommend](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590(v=vs.110).aspx) that you use the "Web Application" format, which is now covered by the "ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework)" option in the "Web" section.

> For new development, we recommend that you choose web application projects. This topic explains that web site projects have some advantages, but many developers who choose web site projects eventually find that the disadvantages outweigh any perceived advantages.

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends upon your usage like If you need to website your site in linux than go for core, need APIs than go for Web API instead of WCF etc